# Вопрос про позиционирование на flexbox

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.projects {
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.projects_con {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul .button2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="projects_con">
      <div class="buttons">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="button2">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="button2">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="button2">Mobile App</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="button2">Illustration</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="button2">Photography</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Есть кнопочки сверстанные flexbox. При уменьшении экрана блоки останавливаются 
в одном месте и дальше перестают позиционироваться по центру (скриншот почему-то не получается загрузить).

Как добиться такого эффекта чтобы блоки не переставали позиционироваться по центру и соответственно первые и последние блоки вылазили за пределы экрана?

Сейчас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: корректнее опишите, какой функционал вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @Марсель Дополнил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так себе это увидел - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/zLMBYb:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

html,
body,
section.projects {
  width: 100%;
}

section.projects {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.projects_con {
  width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul .button2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="projects_con">
      <div class="buttons">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="button2" href="#">All</a></li>
          <li><a class="button2" href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a class="button2" href="#">Mobile App</a></li>
          <li><a class="button2" href="#">Illustration</a></li>
          <li><a class="button2" href="#">Photography</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```